# Search Column A to match a number in column C if True return column B if false return "0"

Tags: excel

I am trying to make data collected in 15 minute increments look like data collected in 5 minute increments with the blank spaces being zero.  I have created a column with Julian date/time in 15 minute increments (A) and a column with Julian date/time in 5 minute increments (C) and the 15 minute increment data is in column B.  I have created a simple formula to check all of column A for an exact match to column C if true I need it to return Column B corresponding to the match in column A, If false it can return 0.

Here is what I have so far with the ?????? being the missing True return formula.  What is the formula to return the corresponding data in column B?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,D:D,0)),"?????????","0")
```

Answer (score 3):

The common way to handle this sort of lookup is using `INDEX-MATCH`.  You may also be able to use `VLOOKUP` but I always prefer `INDEX-MATCH`.

**Picture of ranges** shows the 5 minute times in column `C` with 15 minute data in column `F`.

[image: showing ranges]

**Formula** in `C1` is a combination of `INDEX-MATCH` and `IFERROR`.  The `IFERROR` is used to handle the case of a value not found and returning the `0` you wanted.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$11,MATCH(B1,$E$1:$E$11,0)),0)
```

That formula can be copied down from C1 to the end of the 5-minute times.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample formula looks like it uses different columns that your narrative describes. I will use what I understand from your description as the columns. See my sample image below for clarity.

Time lookups are prime candidates for [15 digit precision floating point errors](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/). This is due to the base nature of time being a decimal portion of a day and the repeating decimals inherent with displaying 60 minutes and 24 hours. This problem is often magnified by using incremental progression vs datum growth.

If you have a base time in A2 and wish to create a series of 15 minute increments from that to fill down the column, do not use something like the following:

```
=TIME(0,15,0)+A2     ◄ generates incremental error growth
```

When you fill that formula down, any error is multiplied as you fill down. Your base display of minutes may not show any obvious errors but if it was displayed as seconds you would likely find that an extra second was added or subtracted every several hundred rows. This is known as Incremental Error Expansion where each successive row adds to the error generated by the previous formula. In short, if you have a hundred of these formulas in a column, any error in the first is multiplied by 100 by the last one.

By always basing the sequential time formula on A2, the error is minimized to a 
single calculation. Change the formula to something like,

```
=TIME(0,ROW(1:1)*15,0)+A$2    ◄ datum growth based on minutes added to A2
```

Even with a datum growth formula you may have some errors on exact matches. Best to wrap the formula in an [MROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mround-function-2f10722d-38ef-4197-be12-a3f02212e637) that allows you to round off the returned value to a specified multiple; in this case to the nearest second.

```
=MROUND(TIME(0, ROW(1:1)*15,0)+A$2, TIME(0, 0, 1))
```

Fill down to get a progressive column of values with a 15 minute increment. You will likely not see any difference in the displayed values but the raw underlying value that is used for the lookup will be quite different. This principle is know as Datum Incrementing; e.g. all progressive numbers are based on a single calculation against the original.

So with a time value in A2 these are the formulas that should be used.

```
8:30:00 AM                                           ◄ starting time value in A2
=MROUND(TIME(0, ROW(1:1)*15,0)+A$2, TIME(0, 0, 1))   ◄ in A3 add 15 minutes to A2 (fill down as necessary)
=A2                                                  ◄ starting time value in C2
=MROUND(TIME(0, ROW(1:1)*5,0)+C$2, TIME(0, 0, 1))    ◄ in C3 add 5 minutes to C2 (fill down as necessary)
```

These will produce the most accurate time increments to be used for an exact match lookup.

Now you can apply a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) paired with a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to retrieve the values from column B. An [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) will catch non-matches and output a *0* instead of the `#N/A` error.

[image: Iime Increments as Datum]

My formula in column D uses an INDEX/MATCH pair. D2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B, MATCH(C2,$A:$A, 0)), 0)
```

There is an alternate formula in E2 using VLOOKUP,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A:$B, 2, FALSE), 0)
```

> Caveat: There is a maximum number of minutes that can be applied with the [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-E3AE5A7B-BD57-44B4-8467-CED98241E087). This is the maximum positive value of a signed integer or 32,767 (about 22¾ days worth of minutes).

Comment: This is an **excellent** write up of an issue I saw while answering this question.  I was trying to do a simple `=A1+5/60/24` copied down, and it didn't work even for the first match which involved just three additions.  I switched over to a formula based on adding multiples to the base time and got the image above.  As you can tell, I was also unaware of the `TIME` formula... that's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate the look-up altogether and just use the index function to reference the cells needed like this:

[image: Formula]

Comment: This is definitely a good approach when the data lines up in a way that it can be used.  For a more polished worksheet, I get nervous seeing `MOD` and `ROW` because it often sets limits on where the formulas and data can reside/start (here in row 1, 4, 7, ...).  I like formulas to work when I cut/paste, and these break in a way that is very difficult to detect.

Comment: True, it makes an assumption that you just want to use every third line.  But if that is the case, it would definitely be a more efficient method as the lookup functions will be time consuming particularly for a very large set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Is a comment warning enough when dealing with potential data loss?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306832/is-a-comment-warning-enough-when-dealing-with-potential-data-loss) and `=TIME(0,ROW(1:1)*15,0)+A$2` I caution that applied ‘liberally’ there may be the risk of loss of data. May depend on machine specifications etc. but trying to fill most of a column with that formula my Excel crashed (after attempting for most of 1-1/2 hours). I’d be interested in the experiences of others, in part because dealing with the least significant digit might be processor dependent.

On my machine I tried comparing:

```
=TIME(0,ROW(1:1)*15,0)+A$2
```

with

```
=TIME(0,15,0)+B2
```

Over 1,000 rows (ie about 10-1/2 days of quarter hours) and found differences (computed, so a possible source of further inaccuracy). The main difference being that the latter accounts for day changes (the integer part in Number format) whereas the former does not. Allowing for integer differences over 1,000 data points there were about 30 that differed by `0.00000000000003`, in Number format, and a further 10 or so by much smaller amounts.

The last data point (09:45 AM on day 10) was one of those exhibiting the larger difference (though not as the accumulation of a series of smaller differences). *Any* difference can be enough for a failure to make an exact match but in seconds that is a difference of about `0.000000002592` by my reckoning, say ~`0.0000026` milliseconds or ~`26` nanoseconds.

Since in my opinion the day (integer part) is likely to be useful, I would recommend series fill by entering `0` in one cell and `00:15:00` in the next, the dragging down to suit. This has no performance impact because the cell contents are values rather than formulae. For the last entry this gives rise to a difference of `0.00000000000005`, ie about twice as much as above, and in some cases as much as `0.00000000000009`, about 78 nanoseconds.

With rounding to the second there are differences of a similar order of magnitude.  However, a comparison on the last series fill result, with rounding to the second, with the last result from `=MROUND(TIME(0, ROW(1:1)*15,0)+A$2, TIME(0, 0, 1))` using [EXACT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/exact.php), returns “TRUE”.

Series fill of an entire column took me about 3 seconds. Then rounding to one second with a formula in another column about 12 seconds.