# How to display hh:mm:ss in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, time

I'm new to Excel VBA. I want to set up a loop that will display the time for each minute on the minute in a new cell.

Is there a way to display only the time (hh:mm:ss) in a cell without seeing the date beside it?  Also, I'd like the time zone shown.  (e.g. Singapore Time, "SGT").

Here is an example of the output I'd like to see:

```
23-Oct-13 10:00:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:01:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:02:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:03:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:04:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:05:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:06:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:07:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:08:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:09:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:10:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:11:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:12:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:13:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:14:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:15:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:16:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:17:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:18:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:19:00 AM SGT
23-Oct-13 10:20:00 AM SGT
...
```

Comment: Do you want to take the values from column A, extract just the time value (hh:mm:ss), and place that into a different column? Is your source data always the same length (i.e. always the same number of characters before and after the time-value)? What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: I was hoping for a code that would provide me a timing from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 automatically . (not extracting and pasting). I'm still doing some research that could possibly help me find an answer. Sorry for not providing you with any codings.. - @eirikdaude

Comment: Then where do you get those time values from? If it's just about the formatting, having a look at [`NumberFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) may help.

Comment: I got the values from a raw data of a Building Load. Hmmm.. Sorry, its not about the formatting. More like inserting a code so that I can get a timing from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 into column A rather than just putting range("A1").Value = 00:00:00 and all the way to range ("A_").Value = 23:59:00 . This will take hundreds of codings to do... -@eirikdaude

Comment: You want to put every time-value from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 into column A, using an increment of 1 minute? Without getting the format displayed in your question? If so, you should put this into your question, as it is very difficult to parse what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This Should do it, have Fun. :-)

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim i&, sTime As Date, TimeStep As Date, Cell As Range
    '// Format range cell to 24Hrs
    With Range("A1:A1440") '// 24H*60M
        .NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS;@"
    End With

    Set Cell = [A1] '// first cell to write
        sTime = "00:00:00"  '// start time
    '// Loop 24hrs
    TimeStep = "00:01:00" '// time increment
    For i = 0 To 1439 ' // 1439 means 1439 cells
        Cell.Offset(i, 0).Value = sTime
        sTime = sTime + TimeStep
    Next i
End Sub
```

Start

[image]

End

[image]

Comment: In general when dealing with times, **you should not add an increment successively**.  This can lead to accumulated round off errors.  It's better to multiply the step by the number of multiples and add that single number: `.Value = sTime + TimeStep * i`.  This is most likely to be an issue if the time is stored on a specific (recent) day because the "number" starts around 47000 or if you are adding seconds instead of minutes.  Related post from @Jeeped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30380424/4288101

Comment: @Byron . Thank you so much ! Sorry it took me a long time to reply :') Yes, it does help . Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

ok, now that you explained a bit in more depth,

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "00:00:00"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "00:01:00"
Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A1440"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve time format you can use:

```
=Mid(A1,11,8)*1 into function bar (with additional column)
```

or into a sub

```
timeOnClock = Mid(MyString, 10, 9)*1
```

then for your first row **`(23-Oct-13 10:00:00 AM SGT) you retrieve 0,416666667`** and you can choice your prefer format

Comment: not going to nit-pick, but did you just copied from my discarded edit the second part of your answer? becuase the variable name is quite uniqe...

Comment: Cohen, I use the same variable name, to be easy undestand.
Your code was correct, I add only the *1 because in this case the result will be transform from text to number
sorry if I bumped

Comment: @Fabrizio Why even do this? You're losing data and formatting it, when just formatting it could get the required result.