# How to increment +1 cell down then concatenate vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to increment a cell and concatenate it through vba

*Example*

In Cell A1 I have a Date example 1/3/2018 comes which will from a `userform` .

I have it where it converts it to text format in B1 showing as 103173.
I have another column with "random" (insert speech about not really random :))integers in column F

so in column c it shows "random"&103173 so in this case it shows 333103173

what I want it to do is go to the next random integer down in column F concatenate the value with the B1 whatever the new date conversion is ...
and add it to C2.

I know I will likely need to go through some kind of loop going through column F,
but not sure how that would look.

Any help would be great!

sort of what I've started below

```
Sub mydate()

    'Dim i As Long
    'Dim j As Long

    'i = 1
    'j = Range("B2000").Value
    'x = Cells(i, 2)

Dim sdate As String
sdate = Format(Range("A1"), "mmddyyy")

Cells(1, 2) = sdate


End Sub
```

Comment: use OFFSET to shift direction from a specified cell.

Comment: I started to work with a +1, didn't have much luck, but  maybe like you said offset cells on F column .. thinking after concatenation... sorry still very new to vba. that would be simpler than running through a loop. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30841761/4539709

Comment: good reference - on offset loop. Thank you!

Comment: Is it always b1 + the next cell value on column F ?

Comment: yes it is it increments the F column